# Calling wait() after posting a runnable to UI thread until completion

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I'm actually in need of waiting for the ui thread to execute a runnable before my application thread can continue. Is the wait()/notify() way a proper way to do it or is there something better for this? What I'm actually doing looks like this:

```
public void showVideoView() {
    try {
        final AtomicBoolean done = new AtomicBoolean(false);
        final Runnable task = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                synchronized(this) {
                    mStartupCurtain.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    mVideoView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mWebView.loadUrl("about:blank");
                    mWebView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    done.set(true);
                    notify();
                }
            }
        };
        mUiHandler.post(task);
        synchronized(task) {
            while(!done.get()) {
                task.wait();
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "showVideoView done!");

        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Thread got interrupted while waiting for posted runnable to finish its task");
    }

}
```

Also when I do this I have to be sure that the thread is not the one of the UI, which happens when I start calling methods from a listener method coming from an interface like MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener.

What do you think?

Comment: "I'm actually in need of waiting for the ui thread to execute a runnable before my application thread can continue" -- why?

Comment: To be able to maintain the sequence of execution in that thread. I've realized that just calling uiHandler.post(myrunnable) doesn't help me to maintain the sequence of instructions I make. Since the execution will be done in another thread, (the one of the UI in my example, which is why almost always I use the post method from the handler object) I wont know when I will get the change of the state in the UI done. I could post a runnable inside that runnable to a handler that goes to a looper that I have, but adding more listeners and callbacks is just crazy.

Comment: There are also some problems that I get with some views in some devices when for example I try to play a video in a VideoView or load a website in a WebView, and those views are still not visible. What results is that if I set the visibility back to visible to those views, the VideoView is not playing anything. So I have to make this to always show the views before setting the content and calling play, or calling loadUrl.

Comment: Are the 'synchronized' necessary? Isn't the 'while(!done.get())' enough to avoid the calling thread to wait for a finished (very short lived) secondary thread, and then, the 'wait' enough for the calling thread to wait for the secondary thread to call 'notify' ?

Comment: I reply to myself : if you don't synchronize on the object, Java runtime will throw an exception : "java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: object not locked by thread before wait()"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks fine to me.

The "done" variable could be a regular Boolean instead of AtomicBoolean since you definitively get/set it's value within the lock. I like that you check the value of "done" prior to calling wait - since it is quite possible the task will have been completed before you ever enter the lock in the worker thread. If you had not done that, the wait() call would go indefinitely since the notify() had already happened.

There is one edge case to consider that may or may not be applicable to your design.   What happens if the UI thread is attempting to exit (i.e. app exit) when the worker thread is still stuck waiting for the task to complete? Another variation is when the worker thread is waiting on the task to complete, but the UI thread is waiting on the worker thread to exit. The latter could be solved with another Boolean variable by which the UI thread signals the worker thread to exit.  These issues may or may not be relevant - depending on how the UI is managing the thread to begin with.

Comment: Accepting this answer after a time has passed without new answers that properly address the problem I try to explain in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Use AsyncTask!

> AsyncTask enables proper and easy use of the UI thread. This class
>   allows to perform background operations and publish results on the UI
>   thread without having to manipulate threads and/or handlers.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: But how would you use it the other way around? It seems to be intended for use from the UI thread to launch background tasks of little duration as the description says. I have a separate thread (actually two, but the other one only does just one thing) where I implemented a looper/handler for my application. This is I need to do tasks in the UI and then resume the execution of this separate thread.

Answer (score 0):

Function:

```
 public static void postOnUI(Runnable runnable,boolean wait) {
    if (Looper.getMainLooper().getThread() == Thread.currentThread()) {
        // Is on UI thread.
        runnable.run();
        return;
    }
    Handler uiHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    AtomicBoolean done = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    uiHandler.post(() -> {
        runnable.run();
        done.set(true);
    });
    if (wait) {
        while (!done.get()) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(20);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage Example:

```
 Utils.postOnUI(headerView::updateUI,true);
```