# Effecting UI changes from a for loop in an asynchronous execution

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, okhttp

```
        for (int i = 0; i < userdataarray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonobject = userdataarray.getJSONObject(i);
            String lat = jsonobject.getString("lattitude");
            String lon = jsonobject.getString("longitude");
            la = Double.parseDouble(lat);
            lo = Double.parseDouble(lon);
            Log.i("LOG", "1");


            Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Log.i("LOG", "2");
                    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(new LatLng(la, lo))
                            .title(category));
                }
            });
```

The code snippet specified above is present in the **onResponse()** method of an **okhttp** call. Essentially, this for loop is being executed asynchronously. Now the problem I'm facing is that the **mMap.addMarker** method needs to be called for all the values of *lat* and *long* as the **for** loop progresses.

I have placed two **Log.i()** printers, one outside the UI updater and one inside. What I want is for the Logs to print alternatively:
**1**
**2**
**1**
**2**
**1**
**2**

but what's happening is 
**1**
**1**
**1**
**2**
**2**
**2**

Is there any way to make it work the way I want to? Please forgive the noob code. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have no idea why do you need that but your answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20179193/calling-wait-after-posting-a-runnable-to-ui-thread-until-completion

Comment: Furthermore - it is much better for performance to accumulate all the markers into a list and then execute a single post _after_ the loop instead of multiple inside.

Comment: One thing you could do is to make your own logger class, that caches messages of type 1, and only prints a message of type 1 when the message of type 2 arrives.

Comment: Thanks, I used an array to store all the values, and then moved to the UI thread. I'm not sure why I tried to do it the other way. Thanks a lot @fukanchik !